# How to read SubRip file content into array of block subtitle?

Tags: c#

I want to read SubRip file content into array of block subtitle.

SubRip content example:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:15,000
A time for us

2
00:00:15,001 --> 00:00:17,001
someday there'll be

3
00:00:17,002 --> 00:00:22,002
When chains are torn by courage born

4
00:00:22,003 --> 00:00:24,003
Of a love that's free
```

**SubRip block Format:**

First line: Index of subtitle

Second line: Interval Time

Third line: Subtitle text

**My Try:**

```
string subRipContent = ReadTextFileFromUrl();
Match[] matches = Regex.Matches(subRipContent, @"^(\d\d)\t(\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d)")
                           .Cast<Match>()
                           .ToArray();
```

**Explain of code:**

I have used Regex.Matches to read subrip block from subRipContent string into an Array. But unsuccess, the array return length of zero.

Note: The parameter subRipContent already has content as the subrip content example above.

**Reason:** The regex format is not correct.

**Requirement:** I need your help to construct a regex format to read block of subrip from subRipContent into an array.

**Result should be an array of string look like this:**

```
    string[] ID = {
[1
    00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:15,000
    A time for us], 
[2
    00:00:15,001 --> 00:00:17,001
    someday there'll be], 
[3
    00:00:17,002 --> 00:00:22,002
    When chains are torn by courage born]};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. It will give array of each subtitle.

```
string subRipContent = ReadTextFileFromUrl();
string[] splitData = data.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Simple and great, but it'd be better to split by `new string[]{Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine}`. Also, `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` is not needed here.

Comment: Great. Where did you get that? It is simple but berfect. Why couldn't I think of it at first time. By the way, thank too much for your help.